# Two colour heat map in python

Tags: python, heatmap

I have the following data:

```
my_array = array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])
```

and

```
df.values = array([246360,  76663,  29045,  11712,   5526,   3930,   3754,   1677,
         1328])
```

I am producing a heat-map as such:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cmap = sns.cm.rocket_r
ax = sns.heatmap(my_array, xticklabels=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"], yticklabels=df.values, cmap = cmap)
ax.set(xlabel='Test Type', ylabel='Number', title='patterns of missingness')
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(40,30), dpi= 20, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
fig
```

and I get the following:
[image]

My question is, how do I get rid of the continuous color scale and select only two different colors: white for 0 and green for 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a `LinearSegmentedColormap` rather than the current cmap you're using.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_cmap', ['white', 'green'], 2)
```

Then pass the `ticks` argument to the `cbar_kws` argument when you call `sns.heatmap`:

```
ax = sns.heatmap(my_array, xticklabels=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
                 yticklabels=df.values, cmap=cmap, cbar_kws={"ticks":[0,1]})
```

Which gives:

[image]

If it's clear what green and white represent, you could also just turn the cbar off altogether with `cbar=False`.

```
ax = sns.heatmap(my_array, xticklabels=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
             yticklabels=df.values, cmap=cmap, cbar=False)
```

[image]